# AdMob Facebook Mediation in Android not working

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

My ad mob account has been limited and I'm receivng error `I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3` when trying to load ads.

I've read that mediation network should still work even if the ad mob account has been limited so I'm trying to add to the mediation facebook audience network (FAN) but I'm having trouble

I've created a facebook business account and liked to AdMob by following this official guide:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook#step_3_import_the_facebook_audience_network_sdk_and_adapter

Then I followed this guide for testing mediation network:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation-test-suite

I added my device as test device both on ad mob ad FAN.

As stated in the log I've also added

`AdSettings.addTestDevice(deviceHash)`
and
`MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration)`

But when run the app and using the mediation testing tool (see picture) to load a facebook ad I still get the error
`I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3`

[image]

This confuses me. It's like facebook mediation is not taken in account! How can I debug more this?

PS:

- I've selected the type of test ad on facebook before trying to load an ad
- I have the facebook app installed and logged in

By the way I've tried integrating the facebook ads sdk directly and I can load test ads by I want to use mediation

This is my MainActivity code:

```
package com.perlabianca.buongiornobuonanotte

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.onNavDestinationSelected
import com.facebook.ads.AdSettings
import com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.MediationTestSuite
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*
import com.perlabianca.buongiornobuonanotte.BuildConfig.AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var adView: AdView
    private lateinit var configuration: RequestConfiguration
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MediationTestSuite.launch(this);

        AdSettings.addTestDevice("0e48fb1f-dd5c-4102-8d93-be6fcc0955dc");

        configuration = RequestConfiguration.Builder()
            .setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("1F642237A220D0BF1833E04E81F1CEBE")).build()
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration)


        adView = AdView(this)
        adContainer.addView(adView)
        loadBanner()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle item selection
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(
            item
        )
    }

    // Determine the screen width (less decorations) to use for the ad width.
    // If the ad hasn't been laid out, default to the full screen width.
    private val adSize: AdSize
        get() {
            val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
            val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            display.getMetrics(outMetrics)

            val density = outMetrics.density

            var adWidthPixels = adContainer.width.toFloat()
            if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
                adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()
            }

            val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
            return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth)
        }

    private fun loadBanner() {
        adView.adUnitId = AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER

        adView.adSize = adSize

        val adRequest = AdRequest
            .Builder()
            .build()

        print("is test-------")
        println(adRequest.isTestDevice(this))
        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello @ilbonte... I got the same problem as you mentioned in your question. Do you get any solution kindly share it, please?

Comment: Hi @WahabRaja unfortunately not

Answer (score -1):

Enable testing mode on facebook monetization manager.

[image]